# Can I avoid re-deploying after changing ascx, aspx, JS, or CSS files for a SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, user-controls, sharepoint-2013

I´m creating an application with SharePoint 2013/Visual Studio 2012. When I modify the aspx or ascx files, I need to deploy the whole application in order to view all changes and it will take almost one minute.

Is it possible to avoid the deployment when I change these ascx/aspx/js/css files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, deployment is only way how to propagate changes when using Visual Studio to develop SharePoint farm solutions.

But you can create JS/CSS/HTML pages using SharePoint Designer and when you will be done, import it to Visual Studio - SPD saves changes directly to SharePoint and you will see result imediatly...

Comment: Actually for ASCX files you can go to the SharePoint server and find in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\` the User Control and just edit the ASCX page in Visual Studio and save it--the changes will be live. You can do the same for the other types of files, too, I'm sure... just haven't tested.